# Is there any provision in Apex that supports SMS Service?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

In Apex there is a provision to send email through Apex class. So similarly is there any provision which enables to send a sms? To expand my question more, I have a situation where I want to send a sms to the user whenever he submits the application form giving him the application number and other information via sms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into the platform for this - your best bet would be to integrate with an existing online provider.

[SMS Global](https://www.smsglobal.com/) have several exposed APIs, including one super simple POST based service, and you can also create your own POST service for responses if required. I've played with this one before and it took an hour or two to get a two-way setup operational.